# Panda's DataFrame dup each row, apply changes to the duplicate and combine back into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, rows, apply

I need to create a duplicate for each row in a dataframe, apply some basic operations to the duplicate row and then combine these dupped rows along with the originals back into a dataframe.
I'm trying to use apply for it and the print shows that it's working correctly but when I return these 2 rows from the function and the dataframe is assembled I get an error message "cannot copy sequence with size 7 to array axis with dimension 2". It is as if it's trying to fit these 2 new rows back into the original 1 row slot. Any insight on how I can achieve it within apply (and not by iterating over every row in a loop)?

```
def f(x):
  x_cpy=x.copy()
  x_cpy['A']=x['B']
  print(pd.concat([x,x_cpy],axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True))    
  #return pd.concat([x,x_cpy],axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)

hld_pos.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply` function of pandas operates along an axis. With `axis=1`, it operates along every row. To do something like what you're trying to do, think of how you would construct a new row from your existing row. Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 4, 6]})

def f(row):
    """Return a new row with the items of the old row squared"""
    pd.Series({'a': row['a'] ** 2, 'b': row['b'] ** 2})

new_df = my_df.apply(f, axis=1)
combined = concat([my_df, new_df], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you  - this is a very good solution. Before accepting you answer, I would wait a little to see if someone comes up with an answer to construct a function that generates 2 rows (original and modified) within the applied function.